# mvc webgrid ajax paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

```
@{ 
    var gridUser = new WebGrid(canPage: true, defaultSort: "CreatedOn", rowsPerPage: 5, 
                            ajaxUpdateContainerId: "Divxyz"); 
    gridUser.Bind(Model.abc, rowCount: Model.User.Count(), autoSortAndPage: true); 
    gridUser.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All); 

} 
<div id="Divxyz" style="display: none">
```

I am using a mvc3 webgrid with ajax paging ... I figured out my solution to do ajax Paging as above.

BUT ..... My grid is at bottom of the page and When I click on page number(It shows # as its linking page), it takes me to top of page moving grid to bottom of page again for every page number click. Please help me on this.

Thanks In Advance
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution for the issue.
I added below script and when I click on page number page doesnt scroll

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('th a, tfoot a').live('click', function () {
            $(this).attr('href', '#DivGridUser-anchor');
        });

    });
</script>
```